# R Gaussian Elimination and qr factorization

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I found the following `R` code using `qr` factorization cannot recover the original matrix. I cannot figure out why.

```
a <- matrix(runif(180),ncol=6)
a[,c(2,4)] <- 0
b <- qr(a)
d <- qr.Q(b) %*% qr.R(b)
```

then `d` is different from `a` in the way that all the zero columns are moved the the right side. It seems that `qr` factorization does not keep the row space.

Comment: You can also use `qr.X` to recover the original matrix `qr.X(b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read the help for `qr` you see that R uses a pivoted QR-decomposition.
So

```
str(b)
```

gives

```
List of 4
 $ qr   : num [1:30, 1:6] -3.2292 0.218 0.0623 0.0371 0.302 ...
 $ rank : int 4
 $ qraux: num [1:6] 1.05 1.11 1.04 1.22 0 ...
 $ pivot: int [1:6] 1 3 5 6 2 4
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
```

Thus you need to apply `pivot` to `a` or the inverse of `pivot` to `d` to line the matrices up correctly. So

```
pivots <- b$pivot
d.ok <- d[,order(pivots)]
all.equal(a,d.ok)
```

gives

```
[1] TRUE
```

You can also do

```
a.p <- a[,pivots]
all.equal(a.p,d)
```

which also results in `TRUE`.

Comment: Good explanation. I feel the pivoting mechanism is not well documented in R.